# who or whom? "The director (whom/who) regarded as competent enough, resigned from the company."

Tags: whom, who

In the sentence"The director (whom/who) regarded as competent enough, resigned from the company.", should i use whom/ who?

The rule is -   **Whom** should be used to refer to the object of a verb or preposition. While **who** should be used to refer to the subject of a sentence. But i'm confused since the director is the subject of the sentence, i should use "who" but it sounds awkward. I'm not sure where i went wrong so please correct me. Thanks.

Comment: As you say, 'director' is the subject. I suggest “The director, who **was** regarded as competent, resigned from the company.”

Comment: It doesn't matter what role *director* plays in the sentence. It only matters what role *who* plays in its clause. If it's the subject, it's *who*. If it's the object, it's quite frankly also *who* anyway. In your case, the problem is that the clause is incomplete. It is missing the verb. And so the pronoun is neither the subject nor the object. It's just hanging there unconnected to the rest. So no matter what you use, *who* or *whom*, both are wrong. You can fix that by omitting it altogether, or by adding a verb. (In any case, the comma you have there is wrong and must be removed.)

Comment: ...if you leave out the commas, it suggests that there was only one competent director. It was wrong to have a *single* comma.

Comment: For example, if you change the sentence to say "The director who was regarded as competent...", as suggested by Weather Vane above, then the verb in the clause is *was*, and *who* is the subject of that verb. So it must be *who*. If, on the other hand, you change the sentence to say "The director whom I regarded as competent...", then the verb is *regarded*, its subject is *I*, and *whom* is the object. So it must be *whom*.

Comment: You shouldn't use that sentence -- it's broken.